Grafana: display all historical data from OpenSearch
Grafana with OpenSearch does not display all values ​​when the selected time range causes more than 10000 values ​​to be displayed in the same query.
I have this:

Grafana v11.1.3
OpenSearch v2.4.1 (I can't change this)
OpenSearch plugin v2.17.1

The documents in OpenSearch have this structure (this is a minimal example):
{
  "_index" : "servers-kpi-2024.08.03",
  "_id" : "2xLuGpEBKtT7YSkXzCFS",
  "_score" : null,
  "_source" : {
    "timestamp" : "2024-08-03T22:04:09.455144",
    "server" : "server01",
    "cpu" : "cpu00",
    "value" : 5.902239702232741
  }
},
{
  "_index" : "servers-kpi-2024.08.03",
  "_id" : "3BLuGpEBKtT7YSkXzCFS",
  "_score" : null,
  "_source" : {
    "timestamp" : "2024-08-03T22:04:09.132781",
    "server" : "server02",
    "cpu" : "cpu01",
    "value" : 0.006805451463441248
  }
}

There are four servers:

server01: has one cpu
server02: has two cpus
server04: has four cpus
server08: has eight cpus

The first document is dated 2023-08-04 and the last one is dated 2024-08-03 (one year). Each CPU usage (per server and per CPU) is updated every five minutes. There are 1576815 documents in total.
Since the number of CPUs is variable, I used the Partition by values data transformation. This works fine and I get the correct number of CPUs in the graph for each server. But, since OpenSearch is limited to 10000 documents per query, I cannot see the full graph when the time range is large. The visible part of the graph depends of the number of CPUs on the server (number of documents in OpenSearch). For example, 45 days:

The query and data transformation are set up like this (this is a minimal example, the real dashboard has variables to select the server and other things):


I tried changing the settings of the following items:

Size, Use time range and Order in Raw data of the query.
Max data points, Min interval and Relative time in the Query options.

In all the changes I was not successful and the complete graph is not visible.
Is there a way for Grafana to tell OpenSearch to summarize the values ​​so that the response does not have more than 10,000 documents? I believe that the number of documents should not exceed the number of pixels of the width of the graph. For your information, I unfortunately cannot change the OpenSearch version or use PPL as the query language.
Thanks a lot.
